# What's the difference between the permissions "edit_published_posts" and "edit_posts"

Tags: permissions

What's the difference between the permissions "edit_published_posts" and "edit_posts"? It's not clear on the [wordpress manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that 'edit_published_posts' allows the user to edit posts whose status has been set to 'published', in other words, live content. The 'edit_posts' allows users to edit unpublished (e.g. draft) posts.

For most bloggers, the distinction is irrelevant, but if you're using Wordpress for a company or a newsroom, you may want all posts to be reviewed by an editor prior to release. In that case you would also not want anyone but an editor making changes to live content.